# trigonometry: $2\cos^2(x)+3\cos(x)-2=0 \to \cos(x)=-2$ OR $\cos(x)=1/2$

Tags: trigonometry

$$2\cos^2(x)+3\cos(x)-2=0$$
How do you get from here to those $2$:

$$\cos(x)=-2 \hspace{5mm} \text{OR} \hspace{5mm} \cos(x)= \frac{1}{2}$$

And is $\cos(x)=-2$ a valid solution?

Comment: Factor $2y^2+3y-2$.

Comment: Yes, it is, but only when x is a complex value. :-) As far as real numbers are concerned, sine and cosine can only be in between +1 and - 1.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $y = \cos x.$

Substitute into your equation: $$2y^2+3y-2=(2y -1)(y + 2) = 0$$ You have a quadratic equation to solve using your favorite method. Then recall that your two solutions represent $y_1 = \cos x_1$ and $y_2 = \cos x_2$.

**ADDED:**

No, $\cos x = -2$ is not a valid solution, since $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$, so we are then left with one solution: $\cos x = \frac 12 \implies x = \cos^{-1}(1/2)$.

Comment: This needs a TU +1

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\cos(x)$ then $2\cos(x)+3\cos(x)-2=0$ gives $2y^2+3y-2=0$. Factors this and back substitute.